# Solution to Black-Scholes (geometric Brownian motion)

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

For a basic stochastic differential equation $$dS_t=S_t(μdt+σdW_t),$$ a classic method to solve it is by letting $f = \ln S$, and when using Ito formula to this
$$df=d\left(\ln(Y(t)\right)=\left(\frac{∂f}{∂t}+\frac{∂f}{∂Y}+\frac 12\frac{∂^2f}{∂Y^2}\right)dt+\frac{∂f}{∂Y}dW(t)$$
as to this answer ["Stochastic Differential Equation solution for Geometric Brownian Motion"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3449346/1167947).

why $\partial f/\partial t = 0$? Although $f = \ln S$, seems not appear $t$, but $S$ is a function of $t$?

why don't need to the rule to composite function? like $\partial f/\partial t = \partial f / \partial s \cdot \partial s / \partial t$, and I think this is not $0$.

for example in classic calculus, if $f(x)=2x^2+3x$, $g(f(x))=\sin(f(x))$, then, $dg(x)/dx=dg(x)/df(x) \cdot df(x)/dx$, and $d(g(x))/d(f(x)) = \cos(f(x))$, $d(f(x))/dx = 4x+3$, so the final result is $d(g(x))/dx = \cos(2x^2+3x) \cdot (4x+3)$. So why here no need to $\partial f/\partial s \cdot \partial s/ \partial t$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what about now? Is it clear enough?

Comment: The function $f$ you are looking at is $S_t=f(t,W_t)=S_0\exp(\sigma W_t-\sigma^2 t/2+\mu t)\,.$ Now apply Ito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You consider the function
$$
f(t,x)=\ln(x).
$$
This function is independent of $t$, so the partial derivative for the first argument is zero.
$$
Y_t=f(t,S_t)
$$
is now depending on $t$ via composition, but the partial derivative of $f$ for its first argument is still zero.

Comment: still a little bit confused. for example in classic calculus, if $f(x)=2x^2+3x$, $g(f(x))=sin(f(x))$, then, $dg(x)/dx=dg(x)/df(x) \cdot df(x)/dx$, and $d(g(x))/d(f(x)) = cos(f(x))$, $d(f(x))/dx = 4x+3$, so the final result is $d(g(x))/dx = cos(2x^2+3x) \cdot (4x+3)$. So why here no need to $\partial f/\partial s \cdot \partial s/ \partial t$?

Comment: Because here you first consider a Taylor expansion of $f$ and then insert $S_t$ and $dS_t$. The Ito formula is the equivalent to the total differential in smooth calculus. Only that here you get a contribution from the quadratic terms of the Taylor expansion as $(dW_t)^2$ is on average $dt$ (while $dt^2$ or $dt\,dW_t$ are "infinitesimally" smaller than $dt$).